# How to create a custom slide effect?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to reproduce the following design page, but I don't know how to make the sliding effect:
[Example design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bECNW.jpg)

Yet, here is the result of my work :
[Design made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSZeY.png)

I've tried many things (Expanded, SingleScrollView, CustomScrollView with specifics Sliders) but I'm unable to reproduce this sliding effect.

Here's example code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =\> runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Recipe recette = Recipe(

      id: "qzerh6kj48ifuy1",

      name: "Quinoa and roasted vegetable salad",

      description: "This Roasted Vegetable and Quinoa Salad is easily customized to suit  your family's tastes, and the herbs and vegetables you have on hand, so I really want you to consider this more a template than a recipe."

                   "Not a fan of beetroot or squash? Try slow roasted tomatoes, fennel, pumpkin or zucchini. Don't like quinoa? No problems; use your favorite grain instead. Mix up the herbs according to what is is season.",

      image: "http://www.gourmandises-epicees.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/court-bouillon-de-poisson.jpg",

      level: "Easy",

      duration: "1800",

      note: 4.2,

      user: User(

        id: "ojkceagv45uj5",

        name: "Camedon Williamson",

        pp: null

      ),

      tags: \[

        Tags(id: "bt654avbt24as", name: "Entree"),

        Tags(id: "ogbzrlvbzenbr", name: "Vegan"),

      \],

      ingredientRecipe: \[

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "azfik5btd4zg",name: "Pavé de saumon"),quantity: "250",mesure: "grammes"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

        IngredientRecipe(ingredient: Ingredient(id: "fa84grt84gza",name: "Tomates"),quantity: "5",mesure: "unité"),

      \],

      steps: \[

        "Découper les tomates en rondelles",

        "Mettre de l'huile d'olive dans la casserole",

        "Disposer les pavés de saumon dans la casserole",

        "Laisser mijoter pendant 10 min sur feu moyen"

      \]

    );

   

    return MaterialApp(

      // Application name

      title: 'Test',

      home: Scaffold(

        body: RecipeViewPage(recipe: recette,)

      ),

    );

  }

}

 

class Ingredient {

  String? id;

  String? name;

 

  Ingredient({this.id, this.name});

}

 

class IngredientRecipe {

  Ingredient? ingredient;

  String? quantity;

  String? mesure;

 

  IngredientRecipe({this.ingredient, this.quantity, this.mesure});

}

 

class Tags {

  String? id;

  String? name;

 

  Tags({this.id, this.name});

}

 

class User {

  String? id;

  String? name;

  String? pp;

 

  User({this.id, this.name, this.pp});

}

 

class Recipe {

  String? id;

  String? name;

  String? description;

  String? image;

  String? level;

  String? duration;

  double? note;

  User? user;

  List\<Tags\>? tags;

  List\<IngredientRecipe\>? ingredientRecipe;

  List\<String\>? steps;

 

  Recipe(

      {

      this.id,

      this.name,

      this.description,

      this.image,

      this.level,

      this.duration,

      this.note,

      this.user,

      this.tags,

      this.ingredientRecipe,

      this.steps});

}

 

class RecipeViewPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const RecipeViewPage({ super.key, required this.recipe });

  final Recipe recipe;

 

  @override

  State\<RecipeViewPage\> createState() =\> \_RecipeViewPageState();

}

 

class \_RecipeViewPageState extends State\<RecipeViewPage\> {

  late Recipe recette;

  double imageHeight = 250;

  Widget buildTags() {

    // Check null value

    if(widget.recipe.tags == null) return Row(children: \[Text("NO TAG", style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey.shade600))\],);

 

    // Otherwise, construct tag objects

    return Row(

      children: List.generate(widget.recipe.tags!.length, (int index) {

        return Row(

          children: \[

            Container(

              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right:05),

              child: Text(widget.recipe.tags!\[index\].name!.toUpperCase(),

                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey.shade600)

              ),

            ),

            (index + 1 != widget.recipe.tags!.length)

              ? Container(

                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right:05),

                  child: Text("•", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))

                )

              : Container()

          \]

        );

      })

    );

  }

  Widget buildTitle() =\> Text(

    widget.recipe.name!.toUpperCase(),

    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)

  );

  Widget buildNote() {

    List\<Widget\> list = \[\];

  

    for(var i = 1; i \< 6; i++){

        list.add((widget.recipe.note! \>= i) ? Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.deepOrange.shade400) : Icon(Icons.star_border, color: Colors.deepOrange.shade200));

    }

  

    list.add(const SizedBox(width:10));

    list.add(Text(widget.recipe.note!.toString(),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 12)));

  

    return Row(

      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,

      children: list

    );

  }

  Widget buildRecipeBy() {   

    return RichText(

      text: TextSpan(

        children: \[

          const TextSpan(text: "recipe by ", style: TextStyle(fontSize:12, color: Colors.grey)),

          TextSpan(text: (widget.recipe.user == null) ? "" : widget.recipe.user!.name!, style: const TextStyle(fontSize:12, color: Colors.black87))

        \]

      )

    );

  }

 

  Widget buildTile() {

    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60;

  

    return Container(

      height: 60,

      width: double.infinity,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(

        border: Border(

          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1),

          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1)

        )

      ),

      child: Padding(

        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),

        child: Row(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

          children: \[

            Container(

              decoration: BoxDecoration(

                border: Border(

                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1)

                )

              ),

              width: maxWidth / 3,

              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                children: \[

                  Text((widget.recipe.level == null) ? "" : widget.recipe.level!.toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 12))

                \]

              )

            ),

            Container(

              decoration: BoxDecoration(

                border: Border(

                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1)

                )

              ),

              width: maxWidth / 3,

              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                children: \[

                  Text((widget.recipe.duration == null ) ? "0": (int.parse(widget.recipe.duration!) / 60).toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 12)),

                  const SizedBox(height: 05),

                  Text("MINUTES", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 12)),

                \]

              )

            ),

            SizedBox(

              width: maxWidth / 3,

              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                children: \[

                  Text((widget.recipe.ingredientRecipe == null) ? "0" : widget.recipe.ingredientRecipe!.length.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 12)),

                  const SizedBox(height: 05),

                  Text("INGREDIENTS", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 12)),

                \]

              )

            ),

          \]

        )

      )

    );

  }

  Widget buildDescription() =\> Container(

    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - imageHeight,

    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

    decoration: BoxDecoration(

      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),

      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85)

    ),

   child: Padding(

      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),

      child: Column(

        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

        children: \[

          Row(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            children: \[

              Container(

                height: 3,

                width: 50,

                decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                  color: Colors.black,

                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))

                )

              )

            \]

          ),

          const SizedBox(height: 10),

          buildTags(),

          const SizedBox(height: 10),

          buildNote(),

          const SizedBox(height: 10),

          buildTitle(),

          const SizedBox(height: 10),

          buildRecipeBy(),

          const SizedBox(height: 20),

          buildTile(),

          const SizedBox(height: 30),

          Text((widget.recipe.description == null) ? "" : widget.recipe.description!, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, height: 1.5, fontSize: 12)),

        \]

      )

    )

  );

 

  Widget buildBody() =\> Column(

    children: \[

      SizedBox(

        width: double.infinity,

        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

        child: Stack(

          children: \[

            Container(

              height: imageHeight,

              color: Colors.grey

            ),

            Positioned(

              top: imageHeight - 20,

              child: buildDescription()

            )

          \],

        )

      ),

    \]

  );

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

     body: buildBody()

    );

  }

}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Bottom sheet" just search for "Flutter bottom sheet" and you will get different ways to implement it, either the default [flutter bottom sheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html), you also can use packages like [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet).... And some big packages provide it by default, for example, [Getx](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#bottomsheets) provides it.... and you can customize its contact

Comment: I also thought about it but on the design example, recipe details are always displayed (no opening animation, modals requires user actions and could also get closed), and I didn't find a way to dynamically change modal height by sliding down.